# How can I enable a button or div hover detection inside a label?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, codepen

I have code for an image gallery created with bootstrap where I'd like a delete button on rollover. However, the div or button (whatever works) is absolutely positioned over an image inside a label, where the whole image is clickable.

My codepen for this is here - https://codepen.io/leecolarelli/pen/ZqMmrw

I have tried placing the `<i class="fa fa-times"></i>` inside a div or a button, and having that div or button outside of the label tag, but it still didn't work.

How can i make the cross clickable?

```
<!-- Start of: Image Entry -->
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 text-center">
       <label class="image-checkbox">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" />
              <input type="radio" id="" name="presetimage" value="" />
              <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
       </label>
</div>
<!-- End of: Image Entry -->

.image-checkbox {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  outline: 0;
  position: relative;
  input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
  }
  input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
  }
  &:hover {
    .fa-times {
      visibility: visible;
    }
  }
  &.image-checkbox-checked {
    border-color: #4783B0;
    .fa-check {
      visibility: visible;
    }
  }
  .fa {
    position: absolute;
    color: #4A79A3;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    visibility: hidden;
    &.fa-check {
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    &.fa-times {
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  }
}

$(function () {
    $('input[name="presetimage"]').on('click', function() {
        $(".image-checkbox-checked").removeClass("image-checkbox-checked");
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("image-checkbox-checked");
    });
})
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: please add this css .fa-check { visibility: visible; } inside the &:hover { } and check.

Comment: Check this codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QZVzvP

Comment: Thanks, i have now added the code.

Comment: @PankajSharma It is not desired to make the fa-check visible on hover. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cross mark can be made clickable as follows,

$('.fa-times').on('click', function(e){
    alert("Cross mark clicked");
});

And also comment the css border color as follows as it appear whole image is selected

&.image-checkbox-checked {
    /*border-color: #4783B0;*/
    .fa-check {
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Technically this answers the question correctly, as its now clickable, so I've marked it as the answer. Ideally i'd also like to know how to stop it selecting the label when the cross is clicked though.

Also, the image border is desired, to show image selection.

Comment: You can probably try something like this **$('label i.fa-times')** instead **$('.fa-times')**, if you want to select specific elements. Go through css selectors once for better understanding.